# How to provide current BeanFactory as constructor argument

Tags: java, spring

I have a singleton class which I would like to be created using Spring's IoC. This class needs to instantiate a dynamic number of other objects using IoC as well. Thus, this class needs the BeanFactory passed in as a constructor argument. How can I do this?

Here is the general structure I was planning. I am fairly new to Spring IoC, so I am also open to changing this structure if it does not fit well in Spring.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ApplicationContext context =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"applicationContext.xml"});

        MySingletonInterface instance = context.getBean(MySingletonInterface.class);

        instance.foo();
    }
}

public class MySingletonClass implements MySingletonInterface
{
    public MySingletonClass(BeanFactory beanFactory)
    {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }

    public void foo()
    {
        for( ..... )
        {
            NeedManyInstances instance = beanFactory.getBean(NeedManyInstances.class);
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to declare constructor as `@Autowired` (make sure that application context [is configured for use of annotation-based configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config) with `<context:annotation-config/>`):

```
@Autowired
public MySingletonClass(BeanFactory beanFactory) { ... }
```

Another option is to make your class implement `BeanFactoryAware` and use `setBeanFactory()` method instead of constructor.